# Limiting and sorting by different properties on couchbase

Tags: couchbase

Given a JSON document on couchbase, for example, a milestone collections, which is similar to this:

```
{
    "milestoneDate" : /Date(1335191824495+0100)/,
    "companyId" : 43,
    "ownerUserId": 475,
    "participants" : [
        {
            "userId": 2,
            "docId" : "132546"
        },
        {
            "userId": 67,
            "docId" : "153"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I were to select all the milestones of the company `43` and want to order them by latest first.. my view on couchbase would be something similar to this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.companyId && doc.milestoneDate)
  {
    //key made up of date particles + company id
    var eventKey = dateToArray(new Date(parseInt(doc.milestoneDate.substr(6))));
    eventKey.push(doc.companyId);

    emit(eventKey, null);
  }
}
```

I do get both dates and the company Id on rest urls.. however, being quite new to couchbase, I am unable to work out how to restrict the view to return only milestones of company `43`

The return key is similar to this:

```
"key":[2013,6,19,16,11,25,14]
```

where the last element (`14`) is the company id.. which is quite obviously wrong.

The query parameters that I have tried are:

- `&descending=true&startkey=[{},43]`
- `&descending=true&startkey=[{},43]&endKey=[{},43]`
- tried adding companyId to `value` but couldn't restrict return results by value.

And according to couchbase documentation I need the date parts in the beginning to sort them. How do I restrict them by company id now, please?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the company id at the start of the array, and because you'll be limiting by company id, couchbase sorts by company id and then by date array so you will be only ever getting the one company's milestone documents

I'd modify the view to emit

```
emit([doc.copmanyId, eventKey], null);
```

and then you can query the view with

```
&descending=true&startkey=[43,{}]
```

This was what worked for me previously..

---

I went back and tried it with [end key](https://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-querying-rest-api.html) and this seems to work - restricts and orders as required:

```
&descending=true&startkey=[43,{}]&endkey=[42,{}]
```

or

```
&descending=true&startkey=[43,{}]&endkey=[43,{}]&inclusive_end=true
```

either specify the next incremented/decremented value (based on descending flag) with end key, or use the same `endkey` as `startkey` and set `inclusiveEnd` to true

Both of these options should work fine. (I only tested the one with `endkey=42` but they should both work)

Comment: this is also returning other company ids after 43.. so if company id 43 has 3 milestones and I'm asking for 5, the last two is of 42's.

Comment: ah, sorry, I did this a while ago; it was good enough for me as I was just doing some application log dumps, which always had enough events.. though I should add a check on application layer to filter them out or something.. I'll go back and give it a try and see if I can get it to restrict to one group.

Comment: Mays be these links will help you : http://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-grouplevel-view-queries-compound-keys and http://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-letter-ordering-view-queries

Comment: "&descending=true&startkey=[43,{}]&endkey=[43,{}]&inclusive_end=true" is not working for me right now for version 3.0, any time the start and end key are same, the query returns nothing. Any idea if this has changed?

Comment: @SumitJain we had a - lot of - problems with couchbase; fix one something else breaks. So we retired it from our stack.. and replaced it with elasticsearch - we have had zero problems since then.. unfortunately, (or fortunately), I have not looked at couchbase since then!

Comment: well, that's interesting, I am puzzled myself, as to why such a basic thing as sorting requires a hack. Thanks anyway for the perspective!